# Pygame Custom rect for collision detection

Tags: python, pygame, collision, rectangles

I have managed to use sprite collide to get a player to collide with another sprite and it works well.

However, the `spritecollide` function only allows it (as far as I can figure out at least) to collide with the rect called `self.rect`

I have a custom rect called `self.hitbox` which I want my player to collide with as the hitbox rect is different size to the inbuilt rect itself

Here is my code for the collision with the self.rect

```py
def collide_blocks(self, direction):

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.block_objects, False)
          
    if hits:
        for i in hits:
            if direction == "x":
              if self.x_change > 0:
                self.rect.x = i.rect.left - self.rect.width
              if self.x_change < 0:
                self.rect.x = i.rect.right 
            if direction == "y":
              if self.y_change > 0:
                self.rect.y = i.rect.top - self.rect.height 
              if self.y_change < 0:
                self.rect.y = i.rect.bottom
```

How can adapt my code to make it collide with i.hitbox instead of i.rect (I = the sprite collided with)

Comment: Couldn't you just make `hitbox` a `pygame.Rect` object and then use [`pygame.Rect.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to do the collision detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th argument of [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) can be a user defined callback function used to calculate if two sprites are colliding:

```py
def hitbox_collide(sprite1, sprite2):
    return sprite1.hitbox.colliderect(sprite2.hitbox)
```

```py
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.block_objects, False, hitbox_collide)
```

Comment: @WilliamRedding I can't see your code. I've given you a general answer, but you have to find the bugs in your code yourself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help with the detection!